# Swing JTable reset TableCellEditor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

`JComboBox` in `TableCellEditor` remember last selected value among different rows and even different `TableModels`. For example select a value on one row, then go to another row, start cell editing and `JComboBox` will have as its current value last select value on the previos row.

How can it fixed?

Comment: sounds unusual (as in: the problem is in the code you are not showing), how about a small runnable example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the value in the [`getTableCellEditorComponent(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html#getTableCellEditorComponent%28javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    JTable table = new JTable(10, 2);
    JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new String[] {"A", "B", "C"});
    table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new DefaultCellEditor(box) {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(
                        table, 
                        table.getValueAt(Math.max(row-1, 0), column), 
                        isSelected, 
                        row, 
                        column);
        }
    });

    frame.add(table);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You didn't even try it, did? because it's plain wrong - editors (nor renderers) are not supposed to second-guessing the caller's value.

Comment: funny indeed - and got what (when trying)? BTW, could you reproduce the original problem? If so, with which jdk version (I faintly remember some weird init bugs around the time of 1.2 ;-)

Comment: Nono, I don't think he/she is talking about a "bug". He/she wants the behavior to be like this...

Comment: ahh ... reading and reading again, could be. What a weird requirement indeed ;-)

Comment: changed my vote: +1 for careful reading and wicked creativity :-)